# Is it possible to upload a folders in .net with all its hierarchy?

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, directory, hierarchy

Is it possible to upload a whole folder, but keep its internal order within folders.
(As Gmail)
Paid additives also help.
I tried the meantime 2 plugins: Slick and Ajax-Uploader-
But they flattened the files into one folder and not keep hierarchy.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: why dont you zip full folder with herachy and upload

Comment: zipping the folder and unzipping at the destination would be the good solution as mentioned by @PranayRana.